# When I change the language of the website, the slug is not translated causing a 404 error

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates, django-i18n, django-modeltranslation

I'm new programming with Django. I'm currently using version 2.2 for my first project.

So far it's going well, my website consists of a landing page with a product catalog which has to work in two languages: English and Spanish.

My problem is that when I try to change a URL from English to Spanish or from Spanish to English, I get a 404 error because the product slug does not get translated.

Let me explain.
For a product, I have a URL structure in English:
mywebsite.com/products_en/item-name_en
In Spanish, it would be:
mywebsite.com/products_es/item-name_es

Both links work well, as long as the corresponding language is active. The problem is that, for example, if I am on the English product page and try to switch to the Spanish page, it tries to take me to mywebsite.com/products_es/item-name_en

I know this question has been already asked here on Stack Overflow but the answers didn't get me to the solution

How can I avoid this? Thank you in advance.

Here's my urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('i18n/', include('django.conf.urls.i18n')),
    path('',include('landing_page.urls')),
    path('',include('products_catalog.urls')),
]
```

My products_catalog urls.py

```
from django.urls import include, path
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.utils.translation import gettext_lazy as _
from . import views


app_name = 'catalog'
urlpatterns = [
    path(_('products'), views.products, name='products'),
    path(_('products/<slug:product_slug>'), views.product_detail, name='product-detail'),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

My products_catalog views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from django.http import Http404
from .models import *


def products(request): 
    products_list = product.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'products_catalog/products.html', {'products': products_list,})


def product_detail(request, product_slug):
    product = get_object_or_404(product, slug=product_slug)
    return render(request, 'products_catalog/product.html', {'product': product,} )
```

My product_catalog models.py

```
class product(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(_("Name"),max_length=100, unique=True)
    description = models.TextField(_("Description"), max_length=2000)
    features = models.TextField(_("Features"), max_length=10000, null=True, blank=True)
    
    slug = models.SlugField("Slug", null=True, blank=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.id:
            self.slug_es = slugify(self.name_es)
            self.slug = slugify(self.name)

        super(product, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _("Product")
        verbose_name_plural = _("Products")
```

slug_es was automatically generated because I use django-modeltranslation

Comment: We probably would need some code here, like your models.py and the views.py and maybe the urls.py too

Comment: @imolitor Thank you! I added the files :)

Answer (score 0):

OK, @Lau, I think this article will help you to solve your issue:

[Django modeltranslation slug problem. When i change language dont go right url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53265833/django-modeltranslation-slug-problem-when-i-change-language-dont-go-right-url)

I also think the slug should be static and not translated as pointed out in a comment in above link.